# Accessing subquery from visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am not able to pull the sub query values from visualforce page. Here is my controller and VF code.Guide me through this please....

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class OpenActivity {

    public List<Contact> actRList { get; private set; }
    private boolean Linked = false;
    public id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    //   public List<Contact> searchedGpIds = [SELECT ID,Group_ID__c FROM Contact WHERE id =:id];
    public List<string> searchedConIds = new List<string>();

    public void ViewData()
    {
        actRList = [Select (Select o.What.Name,o.subject, o.WhatId, o.IsTask, o.ActivityDate, o.Account.Name From OpenActivities o) from Contact where ID=:id];
    }

    public OpenActivity (ApexPages.StandardController sc)
    {  
        //      actRList = [Select (Select o.What.Name,o.subject, o.WhatId, o.IsTask, o.ActivityDate, o.Account.Name From OpenActivities o) from Contact where ID=:id];
        ViewData ();
    }

    public boolean getLinked()
    {
        Return Linked;
    }

    public void setLinked (Boolean value)
    {
        Linked = value;
    }       
}
```

VF Page:

```
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!actRList.o}" var="a">
        <apex:column value="{!a.subject}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
</apex:Page>
```

Error:

> Error: Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.o'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @sfdcfox said you can follow like

```
<apex:repeat value="{!actRList}" var="rowVar">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!rowVar.OpenActivities}" var="a">
      <apex:column value="{!a.subject}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:repeat>
```

Or

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!(actRList.size >0)}">
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!actRList[0].OpenActivities}" var="a">
           <apex:column value="{!a.subject}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

---

Or some other ways

you are getting only OpenActivities records related to specific contact record
So what you can do create `List<OpenActivity>`

```
public List<OpenActivity> lstOpenActivity {get;  private set;}

public OpenActivity (ApexPages.StandardController sc)  {
    List<Contact> actRList = [Select (Select o.What.Name,o.subject, o.WhatId, o.IsTask, 
                                                o.ActivityDate, o.Account.Name 
                                               From OpenActivities o) 
                                      from Contact  Where Id =:sc.getId()]; 
     if(!actRList.isEmpty())
        lstOpenActivity.addAll(actRList[0].OpenActivities);
}
```

VF page

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstOpenActivity}" var="a">
   <apex:column value="{!a.subject}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

---

or looks like you are playing with single contact record then you can use like below

```
public Contact actRList {get;  private set;}

public OpenActivity (ApexPages.StandardController sc)  {

    actRList = [Select (Select o.What.Name,o.subject, 
                         o.WhatId, o.IsTask, o.ActivityDate, o.Account.Name 
                          From OpenActivities o) 
                 from Contact  Where Id =:sc.getId()]; 

  }
```

Page

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!actRList.OpenActivities}" var="a">
      <apex:column value="{!a.subject}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: Thank You Ratan for giving me answers with options. Couple of options worked for me. Appreciate your help and inputs...

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the full name; aliases only work within the query (and are generally useless, unless you're performing aggregate queries). So, you can use `{!rowVar.OpenActivities}` to access the subquery. Since you defined actRList as a list, you have to also iterate over *it* first:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!actRList}" var="rowVar">
    <apex:repeat value="{!rowVar.OpenActivities}" var="openAct"> ...
```

Comment: Why do people use and why is the pattern of using an alias for the object name in the documentation. I do not see any benefit for an additional layer of abstraction. I have always wondered what the utility of it is...

Comment: @Eric In SQL, it's convenient to alias fields and tables to make them shorter, but for SOQL, the only effect that aliases have is during AggregateResult queries: `SELECT COUNT(Id) Sum, AccountId Account FROM Contact GROUP BY AccountId` means that each column can be accessed by `.get('Sum')` and `.get('Account')` instead of "expr0" and "expr1". As for aliasing *objects*, I've never seen a use in the documentation or otherwise.

Comment: @Eric, if I recall, the force.com eclipse IDE auto-generates object aliases in the schema explorer - this could be why some (not me) feel it is a useful idea or they simply copy-paste; o.w I agree with sfdcfox

Answer (score 3):

Since you are focusing on the specific parent record by using a standard controller and the id parameter you can simplify things by just getting the results:

```
public class exampleClass {

    public Contact[] conts {get;set;}


    public exampleClass(ApexPages.standardController con){
        conts = [Select FirstName From Contacts Where AccountID = :con.getId()];


    }


}
```

Not sure you really need the subquery to accomplish what you are doing. Otherwise you will have to do what sfdcfox states